# How to use Plotly to make two dropdown menus to control the subplots

Tags: python, plotly

I am making a plot with subplot 1 and subplot 2. The subplot 1 is the stock price plot, and subplot 2 is the index plot. I want to compare each stock with each index side by side. So, I intend to make two dropdown menus with one controlling subplot 1 and another one controlling subplot 2.

```
ash=JupyterDash(__name__)

stocks=['stock1','stock2']
indexs = ['index1', 'index2']

fig=go.Figure()
dash.layout = html.Div([dcc.Graph(id = 'plot', figure = fig), 
                html.P([html.Label("stocks"),
                        dcc.Dropdown(id='stock', 
                                     options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in stocks], 
                                     value=stocks[0])], 
                       [html.Label("indexs"), 
                        dcc.Dropdown(id='index', 
                                     options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in indexs], 
                                     value=labels[0])], style={'width': '80%', 
                                                               'padding-left':'4%',
                                                               'padding-right': '14%',
                                                               'display': 'inline block', 
                                                               'align-items': 'center', 
                                                               'justify-content': 'center'})])

                                                             
                                                              
@dash.callback(Output('plot', 'figure'),
             [Input('stock', 'value'),
             Input('index', 'value')])

def update_figure(X,Y):
   
    if X=='stock1':
        fig1=make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)
        fig1.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = list(stock1['date']), y = list(stock1['price'])), row=1, col=1)
        
        if Y=='index1':
            fig1.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=index1['date'],
                open=index1['open'],
                high=index1['high'],
                low=index1['low'],
                close=index1['close']), row=2, col=1)
         
            fig1.update_layout(xaxis2_rangeslider_visible=False)
            
        if Y=='index2':
            fig1.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=index2['date'],
                open=index2['open'],
                high=index2['high'],
                low=index2['low'],
                close=index2['close']), row=2, col=1)
         
            fig1.update_layout(xaxis2_rangeslider_visible=False)
            
        return fig1
    
    if X=='stock2':
        .... #same format
        
dash.run_server(mode='inline')
```

It's not working; please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- there are multiple issues with your **dash** **layout**. Have fixed these and re-formatted to make it more readable
- your **callback** is basically ok, but repeated conditional code is not needed if you structure your data appropriately.  For purposes of demonstration I have used **yfinance** data and structured to group by ticker

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt

stocks=['SPY','AAPL', "MSFT"]
data = yf.download(" ".join(stocks), start="2020-01-01", end=dt.datetime.today(), group_by="ticker")

indexs = ["^DJI", "^GSPC", "^IXIC", "^NYA"]
idx = yf.download(" ".join(indexs), start="2020-01-01", end=dt.datetime.today(), group_by="ticker")

dash = JupyterDash(__name__)

fig = go.Figure()
dash.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(id="plot", figure=fig),
        html.P(
            [
                html.Label("stocks"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id="stock",
                    options=[{"label": i, "value": i} for i in stocks],
                    value=stocks[0],
                ),
                html.Label("indexs"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id="index",
                    options=[{"label": i, "value": i} for i in indexs],
                    value=indexs[0],
                ),
            ]
        ),
    ],
    style={
        "width": "80%",
        "padding-left": "4%",
        "padding-right": "14%",
        "display": "inline block",
        "align-items": "center",
        "justify-content": "center",
    },
)


@dash.callback(
    Output("plot", "figure"), [Input("stock", "value"), Input("index", "value")]
)
def update_figure(X, Y):
    fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data[X].index, y=data[X]["Close"], name=X), row=1, col=1)
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Candlestick(
            x=idx[Y].index,
            open=idx[Y]["Open"],
            high=idx[Y]["High"],
            low=idx[Y]["Low"],
            close=idx[Y]["Close"],
            name=Y,
        ),
        row=2,
        col=1,
    )
    return fig


dash.run_server(mode="inline")
```